# Clearing the password store in a mechanize.Browser instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize-python

I need to scrape data from a web site programmatically and am using `mechanize` (v0.2.5) to do so. For reasons over which I have no control, the exact password for the HTTP authentication changes frequently, though in a predictable fashion.

So I've tried looping through each password to be tried, and ignoring the authentication errors, until I find one that works:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

for pwd in various_permutations_of_password():
    try:
        print "Trying password: %s" % pwd
        br.add_password(site, username, pwd)
        response = br.open(url)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
else:
    raise e
```

Surprisingly, this doesn't work, even when the right password has been added. From what I can tell, the problem is that the `Browser` object is retaining and attempting to use the previous, incorrect password(s), rather than using the latest one added.

The best workaround I've come up with is to create a new `Browser` instance on each iteration:

```
for pwd in various_permutations_of_password():
    try:
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)

        print "Trying password: %s" % pwd
        br.add_password(site, username, pwd)
        response = br.open(url)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        pass
else:
    raise e
```

Is there a saner way to do this? Is there a way to get the `Browser` object to "forget" the credentials for a specific site without losing the rest of the stateful browsing information in it?

I've also looked through the library code and don't understand why the underlying implementation of `add_password` isn't overwriting the previous password when I add a new one with the same `url`:

```
class UserAgentBase:
    ...
    def add_password(self, url, user, password, realm=None):
        self._password_manager.add_password(realm, url, user, password)

class HTTPPasswordMgr:
    ...
    def add_password(self, realm, uri, user, passwd):
        # uri could be a single URI or a sequence
        if isinstance(uri, basestring):
            uri = [uri]
        if not realm in self.passwd:
            self.passwd[realm] = {}
        for default_port in True, False:
            reduced_uri = tuple(
                [self.reduce_uri(u, default_port) for u in uri])
            self.passwd[realm][reduced_uri] = (user, passwd)
```